# USB Hub in 'safe' mode?

Tags: macos, usb

I have a powered USB 2.0 hub which suddenly started acting weird. No new devices or anything. It is the same setup as before. All connected devices are still working, except one. The one device (a driverless sound card) did work when connected directly, and it is not USB-powered.

Same problem on two machines, one running 10.9, one running 10.10.

After a lot of disconnecting and reconnecting, it suddenly started working again. I then discovered through System Report (*About this Mac -> System Report ... -> USB*), that the name of the USB hub didn't say [Safe] anymore, so it apparently was in some weird state at some point.

I've attached an image showing how it looked in System Report.

[image]

Has anyone had similar experience?